# Converting string to integer array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of geodata stored as a string, and need to turn into into a array of numbers.

```
var input = "[34.1103897,-118.0398531]"
var output = [34.1103897,-118.0398531]
```

Not sure the best way to do this. Any tips/ suggestions appreciated!

Comment: use `JSON.parse()`

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to convert an array of that format is to use `JSON.parse`.

Simply:

```
var input = "[34.1103897,-118.0398531]";
var output = JSON.parse(input);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is always formatted with no whitespace, you could simply remove the first and last characters, and split on ',':

```
var input = '[34.1303897,-118.0398591]';
var output = input.slice(1, -1).split(',').map(parseFloat);
```

Alternatively, that syntax is technically valid JSON syntax, so you could just:

```
var input = '[34.1303897,-118.0398591]';
var output = JSON.parse(input);
```

However, this could be dangerous depending on where the data comes from.

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse is the obvious choice, but there is also manual parsing with a regular expression (the following assumes you might also want to match a leading '+'):

```js
var input = "[34.1103897,-118.0398531]"
var output = (input.match(/[+-]?[\d\.]+/g) || []).map(Number);

console.log(output)
```

You might consider validating the input or the resulting output regardless of the method chosen to convert it to an array.